# Bibliography just works with some links

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am writing a report on LaTex and I have a problem with the bibliography: it recognizes some references but does not others. I have created a short file with one recognized and one not recognized citation:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Text \cite{polyphenol} \\
Text \cite{wikibetulin}
\bibliography{Database}
\end{document}
```

Here is the .bib file:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Book{buhring,
  title         = {Praxislehrbuch Hilpflanzenkunde},
  publisher     = {Stuttgart: Hautg},
  year          = {2014},
  author        = {Bühring, Ursel},
  __markedentry = {[Felix:]},
}

@Electronic{Hildegard1,
  month = {27 } # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://www.heilpflanzenkatalog.net/heilpflanzen/heilpflanzen-europa/181-birke.html},
}

@Electronic{hildegardvonbingenwiki,
  month = {27 } # mar,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hildegard_von_Bingen},
}

@Electronic{erziehungskunste,
  month  = {27 } # mar,
  year   = {2017},
  url    = {http://www.erziehungskunst.de/fileadmin/archiv_alt/2006/0106p003Scheffler.pdf},
  number = {50},
}

@Electronic{wikibetulin,
  month = {27 } # mar,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betulin},
}

@Electronic{leukozyt,
  month = {27} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.leukozyten-info.de/zytokine.html},
}

@Electronic{wundh,
  month = {27} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://www.draco.de/wunden/wundratgeber/wundheilungsphasen},
}

@Electronic{pflanzenforschung,
  month = {27} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.pflanzenforschung.de/de/journal/journalbeitrage/birken-wirken-forscher-untersuchen-die-heilende-wirkung-10197},
}

@Electronic{hydrophobe,
  month = {27} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://www.deutsche-apotheker-zeitung.de/daz-az/2010/daz-13-2010/betuline-multifunktionale-aktivsubstanzen},
}

@Electronic{leipzigunic,
  month = {27} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://research.uni-leipzig.de/giannis/Lehre/OCF/Naturstoffe/Betulin%20aus%20Birkenrinde.pdf},
}

@Electronic{betulingooglebookse,
  month = {27} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://books.google.ch/books?id=vA8WAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA621&lpg=PA621&dq=Betulin+siedepunkt&source=bl&ots=0dDuhhTCrb&sig=gcCgvAW0u8D3RyvrpX6ds9w-4n4&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif_K3Nl8TTAhXGRhQKHc2KDHYQ6AEILDAC#v=onepage&q=Betulin%20siedepunkt&f=false},
}

@Electronic{betulinleipzige,
  month = {27} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://research.uni-leipzig.de/giannis/Lehre/OCF/Naturstoffe/Betulin%20aus%20Birkenrinde.pdf},
}

@Electronic{nhexanwikie,
  month = {31} # aug,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-Heptan},
}

@Electronic{Ethylacetatwikie,
  year = {2017},
  url  = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essigs%C3%A4ureethylester},
}

@Electronic{unileipzige,
  year = {2017},
  url  = {http://research.uni-leipzig.de/giannis/Lehre/OCF/Naturstoffe/Betulin%20aus%20Birkenrinde.pdf},
}

@Electronic{mikrosub,
  month = {30} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardbedingungen},
}

@Electronic{pharao,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://www.wildfind.com/artikel/der-heilschatz-der-pharaonen},
}

@Electronic{eberswiki,
  month = feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papyrus_Ebers},
}

@Electronic{multitalent,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.zeit.de/2002/09/Multitalent_aus_Weidenrinde},
}

@Electronic{alleskonner,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.natuerlich-online.ch/magazin/artikel/die-alleskoennerin/},
}

@Electronic{brenzcatechinwikia,
  month = {01} # jul,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brenzcatechin},
}

@Electronic{veratrumsaurewikia,
  month = {01} # jul,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veratrums%C3%A4ure},
}

@Electronic{weidemultitalent,
  month = {22} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.zeit.de/2002/09/Multitalent_aus_Weidenrinde},
}

@Electronic{weidenextrakt,
  month = {22} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.docjones.de/wirkstoffe/weide/weidenrinden-extrakt},
}

@Electronic{nina,
  month = {22} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://docplayer.org/24114796-Laborbericht-aspirin-nina-menghini-bianca-theus-anna-senn.html},
}

@Electronic{mediconsult,
  month = {22} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.medicoconsult.de/prostaglandine/},
}

@Electronic{cupaspirin,
  month = {24} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.cup.lmu.de/didaktik/lehrer/materialien/aspirin/aspirin---},
}

@Electronic{salicinwiki,
  month = {24} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salicin},
}

@Electronic{sonntagsz,
  month = {28} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://info.sonntagszeitung.ch/archiv/detail/?newsid=236698},
}

@Article{quendi,
  author = {Qëndresa Hoti},
  title  = {Maturaarbeit - Von der Weide zum Medikament},
  year   = {2014},
  note   = {S.09},
}

@Article{meike,
  author = {Meike Spiess},
  title  = {Salicylsäure aus Weidenrinde},
  year   = {2014},
  note   = {S.18},
}

@Electronic{awlheilpflanzen,
  month = {02} # jul,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.awl.ch/heilpflanzen/betula_pendula/birke.htm},
}

@Electronic{Kresola,
  month = {02} # jul,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kresole},
}

@Electronic{sonntag,
  month = {28} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://info.sonntagszeitung.ch/archiv/detail/?newsid=236698},
}

@Electronic{loewe,
  month = {28} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.loewenapotheke-weener.de/aktuelles/birkenkorkenextrakt/},
}

@Electronic{zeitungde,
  month = {28} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.pharmazeutische-zeitung.de/index.php?id=41439},
}

@Electronic{koop,
  month = {28} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.koop-phyto.org/arzneipflanzenlexikon/birke.php 28.02.2017},
}

@Electronic{heilpf,
  month = {28} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.awl.ch/heilpflanzen/betula_pendula/birke.htm},
}

@Electronic{europa,
  month = {28} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.ema.europa.eu/docs/de_DE/document_library/EPAR_-_Product_Information/human/003938/WC500201153.pdf},
}

@Electronic{docplayer,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://docplayer.org/24114796-Laborbericht-aspirin-nina-menghini-bianca-theus-anna-senn.html},
}

@Electronic{schmelz,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmelzpunkt},
}

@Electronic{chids,
  month = feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.chids.de/dachs/praktikumsprotokolle/PP0096Nachweis_von_Salicylsaeure.pdf},
}

@Electronic{fecl,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenchloridtest},
}

@Electronic{eiscate,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://books.google.ch/books?id=zl3yCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA525&lpg=PA525&dq=Nachweis+Catechin&source=bl&ots=lY31deR_6l&sig=CGdvHE6gOHBmbKiQy3Ntf9DapMo&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-g9SC6__PAhVDOBQKHWXSBnwQ6AEIPDAC#v=onepage&q=Nachweis%20Catechin&f=false},
}

@Electronic{chidsala,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.chids.de/dachs/praktikumsprotokolle/PP0096Nachweis_von_Salicylsaeure.pdf},
}

@Electronic{googlebo,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://books.google.ch/books?id=85KiBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187&dq=Triterpen+eisen+III+chlorid&source=bl&ots=hhIsO4xkX-&sig=sBM-QN54T0lCzMP9yRpZpA40sr8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjeuI_RlbDSAhXDVywKHdI6BNoQ6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=Triterpen%20eisen%20III%20chlorid&f=false},
}

@Book{dtv,
  title     = {dtv-Atlas Chemie},
  publisher = {München: Dt. Taschenbuchverlag},
  year      = {2006},
  edition   = {Bd.1 Allgemeine und anorganische Chemie. -10., korr. u. aktual. Aufl.},
}

@Electronic{oxalis,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.oxalis-acetosella.com/duennschichtchromatographie.html},
}

@Electronic{chemieunter,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.chemieunterricht.de/dc2/citrone/hplc.htm},
}

@Electronic{patent,
  month = {17} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.google.com/patents/EP0810222B1?cl=de},
}

@Electronic{urgeschmack,
  month = {18} # mar,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.urgeschmack.de/was-sind-tannine/},
}

@Electronic{gerbstoffwiki,
  month = {24} # jul,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerbstoffe#Nat.C3.BCrliche_Gerbstoffe},
}

@Electronic{wein,
  month = {24} # jul,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://www.delinat.com/gerbstoff.html},
}

@Electronic{roesten,
  month = {12} # mar,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/food.19680120406/epdf?r3_referer=wol&tracking_action=preview_click&show_checkout=1&purchase_referrer=www.google.ch&purchase_site_license=LICENSE_DENIED},
}

@Electronic{zytokin,
  month = {27} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zytokin},
}

@Electronic{nhexanwik,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-Hexan},
}

@Electronic{vanillinwiki,
  month = {16} # aug,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanillin-HCl-F%C3%A4rbung},
}

@Electronic{saulewiki,
  month = {16} # aug,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A4ulenchromatographie},
}

@Electronic{test,
  month = {16} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.erziehungskunst.de/fileadmin/archiv_alt/2006/0106p003Scheffler.pdf},
}

@Electronic{polyphenol,
  month = {4} # sep,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {www.lci-koeln.de/polyphenole-raters-lotz-lemi-tag-2014},
}

@Electronic{catechin,
  month = {4} # sep,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catechine},
}

@Electronic{homeocatechin,
  month = {21} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://homoeopathie-naturheilkunde.vitanet.de/heilpflanzenlexikon/eiche},
}

@Electronic{chemieeisen,
  month = {4} # sep,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.chemieunterricht.de/dc2/tip/05_15.htm},
}

@Electronic{druck,
  month = {04} # sep,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siedepunkt},
}

@Electronic{flussig,
  month = {05} # sep,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fl%C3%BCssig-Fl%C3%BCssig-Extraktion},
}

@Electronic{heptanwikipedia,
  month = {05} # sep,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-Heptan},
}

@Electronic{saligenin,
  month = {05} # sep,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salicylalkohol},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you please add the necessary bib entries to your question and not put them in some external link?

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you run bibtex after adding the not recognised entry??

Comment: @samcarter Yes I set that everything (pdf+Latex+Bibtex...) compiles when I press the button. Does it really recognize both links? Thanks for your intrest in helping me

Comment: Can you share the terminal output from when you run bibtex? And maybe the .log file from your minimal working example?

Comment: Package natbib Warning: Citation `koop' on page 31 undefined on input line 735.



Package natbib Warning: Citation `heilpf' on page 31 undefined on input line 73
5.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `europa' on page 31 undefined on input line 73
5.

Comment: @samcarter it's always like "Package natbib Warning: Citation 'link1' on page 31 undefined on input line 73" of every citation that doesn't work

Comment: But the question is: what does bibtex say? If whatever editor you use does not show you the output, try to run `bibtex nameofyourfile` in terminal.

Comment: Your code compiles fine under `pdflatex main`, `bibtex main`, `pdflatex main`, where `main.tex` is the LaTeX file.  The message you post as an "answer" looks like you have run `pdflatex Database.bib` instead.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I just found out that some citations are in JabRef (my bibtexprogramme) but if I open the bib-file in TeXworks there are exactly the failing cites missing

Comment: Sounds like you need to make sure you have saved the bib file in JabRef.

Comment: @AndrewSwann that wasn't the problem but I found it out: I can't cite links with an % for example: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veratrums%C3%A4ure All 15 links with this property did't work and all the 53 other worked. But you gave me the important hints with opening the bibfile in an other program. Thanks a lot! I hope I did't take you too much time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that is some of your urls is a `_` used.  You can recognize that if you check the error messages you get in the log file (`missing $ inserted` because `_` is used in math mode to indicate an index writing ...).

You can avoid this errors by calling package `url` (or package `hyperref`).

With the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{buhring,
  title         = {Praxislehrbuch Heilpflanzenkunde},
  publisher     = {Stuttgart: Hautg},
  year          = {2014},
  author        = {Bühring, Ursel},
  __markedentry = {[Felix:]},
}

@Electronic{Hildegard1,
  month = {27 } # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://www.heilpflanzenkatalog.net/heilpflanzen/heilpflanzen-europa/181-birke.html},
}

@Electronic{hildegardvonbingenwiki,
  month = {27 } # mar,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hildegard_von_Bingen},
}

@Electronic{erziehungskunste,
  month  = {27 } # mar,
  year   = {2017},
  url    = {http://www.erziehungskunst.de/fileadmin/archiv_alt/2006/0106p003Scheffler.pdf},
  number = {50},
}

@Electronic{wikibetulin,
  month = {27 } # mar,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betulin},
}

@Electronic{leukozyt,
  month = {27} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.leukozyten-info.de/zytokine.html},
}

@Electronic{wundh,
  month = {27} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://www.draco.de/wunden/wundratgeber/wundheilungsphasen},
}

@Electronic{pflanzenforschung,
  month = {27} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.pflanzenforschung.de/de/journal/journalbeitrage/birken-wirken-forscher-untersuchen-die-heilende-wirkung-10197},
}

@Electronic{hydrophobe,
  month = {27} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://www.deutsche-apotheker-zeitung.de/daz-az/2010/daz-13-2010/betuline-multifunktionale-aktivsubstanzen},
}

@Electronic{leipzigunic,
  month = {27} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://research.uni-leipzig.de/giannis/Lehre/OCF/Naturstoffe/Betulin%20aus%20Birkenrinde.pdf},
}

@Electronic{betulingooglebookse,
  month = {27} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://books.google.ch/books?id=vA8WAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA621&lpg=PA621&dq=Betulin+siedepunkt&source=bl&ots=0dDuhhTCrb&sig=gcCgvAW0u8D3RyvrpX6ds9w-4n4&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif_K3Nl8TTAhXGRhQKHc2KDHYQ6AEILDAC#v=onepage&q=Betulin%20siedepunkt&f=false},
}

@Electronic{betulinleipzige,
  month = {27} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://research.uni-leipzig.de/giannis/Lehre/OCF/Naturstoffe/Betulin%20aus%20Birkenrinde.pdf},
}

@Electronic{nhexanwikie,
  month = {31} # aug,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-Heptan},
}

@Electronic{Ethylacetatwikie,
  year = {2017},
  url  = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essigs%C3%A4ureethylester},
}

@Electronic{unileipzige,
  year = {2017},
  url  = {http://research.uni-leipzig.de/giannis/Lehre/OCF/Naturstoffe/Betulin%20aus%20Birkenrinde.pdf},
}

@Electronic{mikrosub,
  month = {30} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardbedingungen},
}

@Electronic{pharao,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://www.wildfind.com/artikel/der-heilschatz-der-pharaonen},
}

@Electronic{eberswiki,
  month = feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papyrus_Ebers},
}

@Electronic{multitalent,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.zeit.de/2002/09/Multitalent_aus_Weidenrinde},
}

@Electronic{alleskonner,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.natuerlich-online.ch/magazin/artikel/die-alleskoennerin/},
}

@Electronic{brenzcatechinwikia,
  month = {01} # jul,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brenzcatechin},
}

@Electronic{veratrumsaurewikia,
  month = {01} # jul,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veratrums%C3%A4ure},
}

@Electronic{weidemultitalent,
  month = {22} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.zeit.de/2002/09/Multitalent_aus_Weidenrinde},
}

@Electronic{weidenextrakt,
  month = {22} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.docjones.de/wirkstoffe/weide/weidenrinden-extrakt},
}

@Electronic{nina,
  month = {22} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://docplayer.org/24114796-Laborbericht-aspirin-nina-menghini-bianca-theus-anna-senn.html},
}

@Electronic{mediconsult,
  month = {22} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.medicoconsult.de/prostaglandine/},
}

@Electronic{cupaspirin,
  month = {24} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.cup.lmu.de/didaktik/lehrer/materialien/aspirin/aspirin---},
}

@Electronic{salicinwiki,
  month = {24} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salicin},
}

@Electronic{sonntagsz,
  month = {28} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://info.sonntagszeitung.ch/archiv/detail/?newsid=236698},
}

@Article{quendi,
  author  = {Qëndresa Hoti},
  title   = {Maturaarbeit - Von der Weide zum Medikament},
  journal = {Missing},
  year    = {2014},
  note    = {S.09},
}

@Article{meike,
  author = {Meike Spiess},
  title  = {Salicylsäure aus Weidenrinde},
  year   = {2014},
  note   = {S.18},
}

@Electronic{awlheilpflanzen,
  month = {02} # jul,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.awl.ch/heilpflanzen/betula_pendula/birke.htm},
}

@Electronic{Kresola,
  month = {02} # jul,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kresole},
}

@Electronic{sonntag,
  month = {28} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://info.sonntagszeitung.ch/archiv/detail/?newsid=236698},
}

@Electronic{loewe,
  month = {28} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.loewenapotheke-weener.de/aktuelles/birkenkorkenextrakt/},
}

@Electronic{zeitungde,
  month = {28} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.pharmazeutische-zeitung.de/index.php?id=41439},
}

@Electronic{koop,
  month = {28} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.koop-phyto.org/arzneipflanzenlexikon/birke.php 28.02.2017},
}

@Electronic{heilpf,
  month = {28} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.awl.ch/heilpflanzen/betula_pendula/birke.htm},
}

@Electronic{europa,
  month = {28} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.ema.europa.eu/docs/de_DE/document_library/EPAR_-_Product_Information/human/003938/WC500201153.pdf},
}

@Electronic{docplayer,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://docplayer.org/24114796-Laborbericht-aspirin-nina-menghini-bianca-theus-anna-senn.html},
}

@Electronic{schmelz,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmelzpunkt},
}

@Electronic{chids,
  month = feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.chids.de/dachs/praktikumsprotokolle/PP0096Nachweis_von_Salicylsaeure.pdf},
}

@Electronic{fecl,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenchloridtest},
}

@Electronic{eiscate,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://books.google.ch/books?id=zl3yCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA525&lpg=PA525&dq=Nachweis+Catechin&source=bl&ots=lY31deR_6l&sig=CGdvHE6gOHBmbKiQy3Ntf9DapMo&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-g9SC6__PAhVDOBQKHWXSBnwQ6AEIPDAC#v=onepage&q=Nachweis%20Catechin&f=false},
}

@Electronic{chidsala,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.chids.de/dachs/praktikumsprotokolle/PP0096Nachweis_von_Salicylsaeure.pdf},
}

@Electronic{googlebo,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://books.google.ch/books?id=85KiBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187&dq=Triterpen+eisen+III+chlorid&source=bl&ots=hhIsO4xkX-&sig=sBM-QN54T0lCzMP9yRpZpA40sr8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjeuI_RlbDSAhXDVywKHdI6BNoQ6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=Triterpen%20eisen%20III%20chlorid&f=false},
}

@Book{dtv,
  title     = {dtv-Atlas Chemie},
  publisher = {München: Dt. Taschenbuchverlag},
  year      = {2006},
  edition   = {Bd.1 Allgemeine und anorganische Chemie. -10., korr. u. aktual. Aufl.},
}

@Electronic{oxalis,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.oxalis-acetosella.com/duennschichtchromatographie.html},
}

@Electronic{chemieunter,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.chemieunterricht.de/dc2/citrone/hplc.htm},
}

@Electronic{patent,
  month = {17} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.google.com/patents/EP0810222B1?cl=de},
}

@Electronic{urgeschmack,
  month = {18} # mar,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.urgeschmack.de/was-sind-tannine/},
}

@Electronic{gerbstoffwiki,
  month = {24} # jul,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerbstoffe#Nat.C3.BCrliche_Gerbstoffe},
}

@Electronic{wein,
  month = {24} # jul,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://www.delinat.com/gerbstoff.html},
}

@Electronic{roesten,
  month = {12} # mar,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/food.19680120406/epdf?r3_referer=wol&tracking_action=preview_click&show_checkout=1&purchase_referrer=www.google.ch&purchase_site_license=LICENSE_DENIED},
}

@Electronic{zytokin,
  month = {27} # apr,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zytokin},
}

@Electronic{nhexanwik,
  month = {27} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-Hexan},
}

@Electronic{vanillinwiki,
  month = {16} # aug,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanillin-HCl-F%C3%A4rbung},
}

@Electronic{saulewiki,
  month = {16} # aug,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A4ulenchromatographie},
}

@Electronic{test,
  month = {16} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.erziehungskunst.de/fileadmin/archiv_alt/2006/0106p003Scheffler.pdf},
}

@Electronic{polyphenol,
  month = {4} # sep,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {www.lci-koeln.de/polyphenole-raters-lotz-lemi-tag-2014},
}

@Electronic{catechin,
  month = {4} # sep,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catechine},
}

@Electronic{homeocatechin,
  month = {21} # feb,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://homoeopathie-naturheilkunde.vitanet.de/heilpflanzenlexikon/eiche},
}

@Electronic{chemieeisen,
  month = {4} # sep,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {http://www.chemieunterricht.de/dc2/tip/05_15.htm},
}

@Electronic{druck,
  month = {04} # sep,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siedepunkt},
}

@Electronic{flussig,
  month = {05} # sep,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fl%C3%BCssig-Fl%C3%BCssig-Extraktion},
}

@Electronic{heptanwikipedia,
  month = {05} # sep,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-Heptan},
}

@Electronic{saligenin,
  month = {05} # sep,
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salicylalkohol},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % <===========================================
\usepackage{hyperref} % <===============================================

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Text \cite{polyphenol} \\ \nocite{*} % <================================
Text \cite{wikibetulin}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

you get the following result without errors or warnings (except the one caused by package `filecontents` to have bib file and TeX code in one MWE):

[image]

BTW: I corrected a typo in your first bib entry: it is `Praxislehrbuch Heilpflanzenkunde` instead of `Praxislehrbuch Hilpflanzenkunde` ...