# Another Bibliography problem

Tags: bibliographies

I have been searching on the Internet for the fix to this problem, but I am not able to pin down the issue.

So, I am writing a long document, consisting on several tex files. I am following the following template: [http://www.cs.mun.ca/~donald/metathesis/](http://www.cs.mun.ca/%7Edonald/metathesis/)

It works perfectly well, except with an issue I am having with the bibliography. I am pretty sure it has to do with the syntax I am using with the bibliography, but I am not able to find the problem. I also used the JabRef "Check Integrity" function. Nothing major was found.

Nonetheless, only one bibliography entry seems to be recognized.

As an example the (only) reference that is recognized is:

```
@article{RefWorks:doc:5f4be6bfe4b08c34f385f2d8,
        author={Francisco Gallardo and Antonio Perez Yuste},
        year={2020},
        title={SCER Spoofing Attacks on the Galileo Open Service and Machine Learning Techniques for End-User Protection},
        journal={IEEE access},
        volume={8},
        pages={85515-85532},
        note={},
        doi={10.1109/ACCESS.2020.2992119}
        }
```

An example of one not recognized (both are in the same bib file, and I check the name in the bib file and the "cite" command in the tex file and both are the same):

```
@Article{RefWorks:doc:5f4b40bfe4b077408a2642de,
  author  = {Gustav Lindstrom and Giovanni Gasparini},
  title   = {The Galileo satellite system and its security implications},
  journal = {The Galileo satellite system and its security implications},
  year    = {2003},
  note    = {Bibl. : p. 35-36.;},
}
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

PS: It may be similar to [Bibliography just works with some links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390412/bibliography-just-works-with-some-links)  but it is not the same as I have no "_" in the bibliography. I also tried the suggested solution and it does not work for my case.

Comment: Show a small complete example that doesn't work. Show also the content of the blg-file (that is the log from the bibtex run).

Comment: I don´t know whether that will be very helpful, it implies I am only using once single reference, which is not the case. You can find here the file itself: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xa2wJfwjgc5kIlJxudsYP4f_TuRw3KHl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In Chap4.tex the second paper is cited:

`\subsection{Goals of the Galileo development}
The main reasons for the development of this European system system were~\cite{RefWorks:doc:5f4b40bfe4b077408a2642de}:`

Comment: And thanks for the support btw!

Comment: an example that reads nearly 10 aux-files is not a small example. Create a new document in an empty folder and copy your bib-file and then try this, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted out. Just in case somebody else finds a similar issue with the Thesis template in http://www.cs.mun.ca/%7Edonald/metathesis/

1. Run the normal compilation by making the make thesis.pdf
2. Manually run bibtex: bibtex thesis.aux
3. Run again the make thesis.pdf

Done. There you have it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce your issue with the following example:
The LaTeX file `a.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
First paper \cite{RefWorks:doc:5f4be6bfe4b08c34f385f2d8} and
second paper \cite{RefWorks:doc:5f4b40bfe4b077408a2642de}.
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{a,b}
\end{document}
```

The BibTeX file `a.bib`:

```
@article{RefWorks:doc:5f4be6bfe4b08c34f385f2d8,
  author =   {Francisco Gallardo and Antonio Perez Yuste},
  year =     2020,
  title =    {SCER Spoofing Attacks on the Galileo Open Service
                  and Machine Learning Techniques for End-User
                  Protection},
  journal =  {IEEE access},
  volume =   8,
  pages =    {85515-85532},
  doi =      {10.1109/ACCESS.2020.2992119}
}
```

The BibTeX file `b.bib`:

```
@Article{RefWorks:doc:5f4b40bfe4b077408a2642de,
  author =   {Gustav Lindstrom and Giovanni Gasparini},
  title =    {The Galileo satellite system and its security
                  implications},
  journal =  {The Galileo satellite system and its security
                  implications},
  year =     2003,
  note =     {Bibl. : p. 35-36.;},
}
```

[image]